# Equality case in metric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces, triangle-inequality

I have a question. Let $(X,d)$ a metric space. Then, for all $x,y \in X$, we have the triangle inequality : $d(x,y)+d(y,z)\geq d(x,z)$.

But, in what case we have the equality in the triangle inequality ? What is a necessary and sufficient condition for : $d(x,y)+d(y,z) =d(x,z)$ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, there is no geometric condition equivalent to that equality.

You can sometimes state one if you have more information about the space. You should be able to see one for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Even in $\Bbb R^n$, I suspect that there are metrics induced by norm where the equality case is far from being trivial

Comment: @Surb Indeed. My answer is for the default natural metric.

Comment: @EthanBolker for R^n, is that convexity ?

Comment: @ztg02 Pretty much. $y$ must lie on the line segment joining $x$ and $z$.

Comment: For another interesting example consider $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the metric $d(x,y)=0$ if $x=y$ and $d(x,y)=1$ if $x \neq 1$. What can you conclude about $x,y,z$ if the triangle inequality is an equality?

Comment: @quarague: I guess you meant $d(x, y) = 1$ if $x \ne y$, i.e. the [discrete metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space)

Comment: @math54321 Yes that is what I meant. Just saw the typo in my comment, it should not read $x \neq 1$ but rather $x \neq y$, then this is an explicit description of the discrete metric.

Comment: In light of this comment discussion (and in spite of the first line of this answer), here is a "geometric" condition: the set of points $y$ for which $d(x,y) + d(y,z) = d(x,z)$ is precisely the line segment between $x$ and $z$, as defined by $d$

Comment: @math54321 What does "line segment" mean in a general metric space with no other known structure? What can that be other than the condition that the distances add as in the question?

Comment: I'm not saying anything different, just pointing out how to interpret the equality condition. A priori "line segment" would not seem to be defined in a general metric space, but this in fact gives a definition